# Specify war in gradle's tomcatRunWar

Tags: gradle

I'm playing with the [tomcat plugin](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-tomcat-plugin) for gradle and in my build/tmp/tomcatRun/work/Tomcat/localhost/myWebApp directory its empty.  Is there a way for me to specify the location of my war to deploy?

I tried

```
[tomcatRun, tomcatRunWar]*.destinationDir= new File("$buildDir/libs").getAbsoluteFile().getPath()
```

and

```
[tomcatRun, tomcatRunWar]*.warDirectory= new File("$buildDir/libs").getAbsoluteFile().getPath()
```

**Update**

I've added the build scripts below.  When I run my new tasks I've been running

```
gradle build integrationTest
```

Here is a snippet from the parent build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        add(new org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.URLResolver()) {
            name = 'GitHub'
            addArtifactPattern 'http://cloud.github.com/downloads/[organisation]/[module]/[module]-[revision].[ext]'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'bmuschko:gradle-tomcat-plugin:0.9.2'
    }

}

allprojects {
  apply plugin: "java"
  apply plugin: "eclipse"
  apply plugin: "idea"

  ext.springVersion = "3.1.1.RELEASE"
  ext.hibernateVersion = "3.6.7.Final"
  ext.mysqlVersion = "5.1.20"
  ext.tomcatVersion = "7.0.26"
  ext.junitVersion = "4.10"
  ext.httpClientVersion = "4.2"
  ext.pdfboxVersion = "1.7.1"
  ext.resxWebserviceVersion = "10.4.2"

  loadConfiguration()
}
```

and my webapps build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: "maven"
apply plugin: "war"
apply plugin: "tomcat"

def now = new Date()

def cssDir = new File("truexpense-web/src/main/webapp/css").getAbsoluteFile().getPath()
def minCssName = 'all-min.css'
def jsDir = new File("truexpense-web/src/main/webapp/js").getAbsoluteFile().getPath()
def minJsName = 'all-min.js'

ext.requestor = ''
ext.fromAddress = ''
ext.replyAddress = ''
ext.formattedDate = now.format('dd MMM yyy HH:mm')
ext.product = 'Truexpense'

configurations {
  deployerJars
  jasper
  mail
}

dependencies {

  //Compile time but not included dependencies
  providedCompile "javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1"
  providedCompile "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:$tomcatVersion"

  //Compile time dependencies
  compile project(":truexpense-domain")
  compile project(":truexpense-repository")
  compile project(":truexpense-service")
  compile "org.springframework:spring-core:$springVersion"
  compile "org.springframework:spring-web:$springVersion"
  compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:$hibernateVersion"
  compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-envers:$hibernateVersion"
  compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:$hibernateVersion"
  compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:4.2.0.Final"
  compile "commons-io:commons-io:2.3"
  compile "commons-codec:commons-codec:1.6"
  compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:3.1.0.RELEASE"
  compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:3.1.0.RELEASE"
  compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:3.1.0.RELEASE"
  compile "javax.mail:mail:1.4"
  compile "mysql:mysql-connector-java:$mysqlVersion"
  compile "com.google.visualization:visualization-datasource:1.0.2"
  compile "org.ostermiller:utils:1.07.00"
  compile "net.sf.ofx4j:ofx4j:1.4"
  compile "org.jpedal:jbig2:1"
  compile "org.apache.pdfbox:txp-fontbox:$pdfboxVersion"
  compile "org.apache.pdfbox:txp-jempbox:$pdfboxVersion"
  compile "org.apache.pdfbox:txp-pdfbox:$pdfboxVersion"
  compile "taglibs:taglibs-unstandard:1"
  compile "org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.7"
  compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:$httpClientVersion"

  //Runtime only dependencies
  runtime "commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils-core:1.8.3"
  runtime "joda-time:joda-time:2.1"
  runtime "org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:3.1.0.RELEASE"
  runtime "org.springframework:spring-beans:$springVersion"
  runtime "org.springframework:spring-context:$springVersion"
  runtime "org.springframework:spring-core:$springVersion"
  runtime "org.springframework:spring-expression:$springVersion"
  runtime "org.springframework:spring-instrument:$springVersion"
  runtime "org.springframework:spring-instrument-tomcat:$springVersion"
  runtime "org.springframework:spring-jdbc:$springVersion"
  runtime "org.springframework:spring-jms:$springVersion"
  runtime "org.springframework:spring-orm:$springVersion"
  runtime "org.springframework:spring-oxm:$springVersion"
  runtime "org.springframework:spring-tx:$springVersion"
  runtime "org.springframework:spring-web:$springVersion"
  runtime "org.springframework:spring-webmvc:$springVersion"
  runtime ("commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.2.2") {
    exclude group: "javax.servlet", module: "javax.servlet-api"
    exclude group: "portlet-api"
  }
  runtime ("javax.servlet:jstl:1.2") {
    exclude group: "javax.servlet", module: "javax.servlet-api"
    exclude group: "javax.servlet", module: "jsp-api"
  }

  //Test only dependencies
  tomcat "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-dbcp:${tomcatVersion}"
  tomcat "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:${tomcatVersion}",
         "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:${tomcatVersion}"
  tomcat("org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:${tomcatVersion}") {
      exclude group: 'org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler', module: 'ecj'

  }

  //Deployments
  deployerJars "org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-http:1.0-beta-2"

  [tomcatRun, tomcatRunWar]*.httpPort = 8090
  [tomcatRun, tomcatStop]*.stopPort = 8081
  [tomcatRun, tomcatStop]*.stopKey = 'stopKey'

  task integrationTest(type: Test) {
      include '**/*IntegrationTest.*'

      doFirst {
          tomcatRun.daemon = true
          tomcatRun.execute()
      }

      doLast {
          tomcatStop.execute()
      }
  }

  test {
      exclude '**/*IntegrationTest.*'
  }

}


war {
  baseName='truexpense'
  eachFile {
    if (it.name == 'login_css_include.jsp') {
      it.expand(loginCSS: "login-min.css?t=${now.getTime()}")
    }
    else if (it.name == 'all_css_include.jsp') {
      it.expand(allCSS: "all-min.css?t=${now.getTime()}")
    }
    else if (it.name == 'all_js_include.jsp') {
      it.expand(allJS: "all-min.js?t=${now.getTime()}")
    }
  }
}

task deploy << { deploy() }

task minifyCSS << {
  def files = fileTree(dir: "${cssDir}", includes: [
    "analysis.css",
    "header.css",
    "footer.css",
    "blocks.css",
    "chosen.css",
    "grids.css",
    "space.css",
    "dataTables.css",
    "newCore.css",
    "core.css",
    "skin_clean.css",
    "plugins.css",
    "css3.css",
    "jquery-ui.css",
    "jquery.lightbox-0.5.css",
    "jqueryFileTree.css",
    "jquery.qtip.css",
    "expense.css",
    "report.css",
    "zentab.css"
  ]).getFiles().sort({it.name})
  concatenate("${cssDir}/all.css", files)
  yuiCompressor("${cssDir}/all.css", "${cssDir}/${minCssName}")
  yuiCompressor("${cssDir}/login.css", "${cssDir}/login-min.css")
}

task minifyJS << {
  def files = fileTree(dir: "${jsDir}", excludes:[
    'all*.js',
    'jqtouch*.js'
  ]).getFiles().sort({it.name})
  concatenate("${jsDir}/all.js", files)
  yuiCompressor("${jsDir}/all.js", "${jsDir}/${minJsName}")
}

def yuiCompressor(from, to) {
  ant.java(jar:"tools/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar", fork: true, failonerror: true) {
    arg(value: from)
    arg(value: "-o")
    arg(value: to)
  }
}

def concatenate(filePath, files) {
  File file = new File(filePath)
  if (file.exists()) {
    file.write("")
  }
  files.each { File f ->
    file.append(f.getText() + '\n')
  }
}

def deploy() {
  println "Deleting ${tomcatHome}/webapps/${war.baseName}"
  delete "${tomcatHome}/webapps/${war.baseName}"
  println "Deleting ${tomcatHome}/work/Catalina/localhost/${war.baseName}"
  delete "${tomcatHome}/work/Catalina/localhost/${war.baseName}"
  println "Copying ${war.archiveName} to ${tomcatHome}/webapps"
  copy {
    from war.archivePath
    into "${tomcatHome}/webapps"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to build the WAR file and deploy it to an external Tomcat container?

Comment: no we have a deploy path that copies from the war.archivePath to our tomcat home.  My goal with this is for integration testing.  When my integration task runs tomcatRun and I get an exception "java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml]"  When I look in the work directory listed above nothing is deployed.  Please let me know if you have more questions!

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't get what you are trying to achieve. The tasks `tomcatRun` and `tomcatRunWar` don't have the properties `destinationDir` and `warDirectory` you are trying to set. Can you post your full build script? When you refer to Tomcat home does that mean that a local Tomcat installation is involved?

Comment: Ok, I've added the build scripts.  I hope that helps!

Comment: The directory `build/tmp/tomcatRun` is created by the embedded Tomcat implementation. It does not reflect an exploded WAR file structure. The Tomcat plugin points to the web app classpath internally at runtime. Does this issue only occur when trying to run the integration tests or in general when you run `tomcatRun`? When running `gradle war` does the WAR file contain your Spring context file?

Comment: I do get the same error when I run tomcatRun.  When I look at my war in the build/libs dir the applicationContext is in WEB-INF/classes.  Deploying to my local tomcat works as well.  I really appreciate you working through this with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you reference your `applicationContext.xml` in your `web.xml`? If you use the full path (`/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml`) then I'd probably change it to search for it on the classpath:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: gotta love one line fixes.  Thanks for sticking with me and the suggestion!